# A word for weariness after travelling?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word meaning something along the lines of *weary, haggard or generally not at one's best after a long journey*? Something like *travel-worn*, but better?

As a compelling motivating example, I offer you my twelve-week-old son on return from his grandparents':

[image: weary-worn]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually
***travel-weary*** and ***travel-worn*** are likely your best options:
[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/travel-weary) defines it:

> **travel-weary** (ˈtrævəlˌwɪərɪ)  or travel-worn
>
> tired or exhausted as a result of travelling   ⇒ "It's hard to rouse a *travel-weary* body from the king-size bed and immerse yourself in the city."

Answer (score 4):

There is ***wayworn*** as a single word. (also *way-worn*). The usage of the word has declined in recent decades but there is still contemporary usage. [See: [Google Ngram]](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=travel-worn%2Ctravelworn%2Cway-worn%2Cwayworn&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctravel%20-%20worn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctravelworn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cway%20-%20worn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwayworn%3B%2Cc0)

> worn or wearied by travel: 
>   *She was wayworn after the long trip.* 
>   <sub>[[Dictionary.com]](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wayworn)</sub>

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226532?redirectedFrom=wayworn&) lists the figurative usage also:

> *fig.* 1848   Thackeray *Vanity Fair* liii. 478     That night..she prayed humbly for that poor wayworn sinner.

Answer (score 3):

There's also **road-weary*

> The traffic control the police put in place indicated a visible
>   agreement that the rancher could continue to take money from the
>   road-weary pilgrims ... a little insurance. [(*The Calling*)](https://www.wordnik.com/words/road-weary)

This appears to be [rising](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=road-weary%2C%20travel-weary&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Croad%20-%20weary%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctravel%20-%20weary%3B%2Cc0) vis-a-vis travel-weary.

Answer (score 3):

*Road fatigue* and the more general term [*travel fatigue*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_lag#Travel_fatigue) describe the adverse effects of travel on one's system. From Wikipedia:

> **Travel fatigue** is general fatigue, disorientation and headache caused by a disruption in routine, time spent in a cramped space with little chance to move around, a low-oxygen environment, and dehydration caused by limited food and dry air.

From the latter term can be derived the adjectival expression *fatigued by travel.*

Answer (score 1):

If your flying then how about "jet lag"; a general feeling of fatigue and disorientation often experienced by travellers by jet aircraft who cross several time zones in relatively few hours.

Comment: Though the image in the question looks more like car lag.

Comment: Downvoted for (1) the spelling mistake, and (2) because the OP is asking about weariness from travel not circadian dysrhythmia (jet lag).

Answer (score -5):

**Enervated** - means exhausted or worn out
**Languid** means drooping

The child was enervated after a long drive in the car.

The child seemed languid after a long hard day of visiting relatives

Websters dictionary

Comment: Neither of those words is specifically related to traveling, which is what OP's question is asking for.

Comment: @nicole After traveling a lot one has a sudden lack of energy which is the definition of enervated. If the traveler is mopey then it can also imply languid. Depending on the state of the individual I offer both. Lack of strength of just bummed out. Both have to do with traveling as I have traveled extensively.

Comment: They _can_ be used in relation to traveling, but they are not _specifically_ used only for traveling, like "travel-worn," "travel-weary," "road weary," etc. are.